# How to test receipt of the same method with different arguments on different instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have my method like

```
def my_method
  MyClass.new.track(arg1, arg2)

  if satisfies_some_condition
    2.times { MyClass.new.track(arg3, arg4) }
  end
end
```

In `RSpec`, I want to test receipt of #track

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:track).with(arg1, arg2)
expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:track).with(arg3, arg4).twice
```

But I am getting this error

> The message 'track' was received by `#<MyClass:70362069595680 >` but has 
>   already been received by `#<MyClass:0x007ffce788e460>`

It seems [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/58) it's suggested that it should be resolved by upgrading to `RSpec-mocks v3.6.0`  But I am still getting the same error even after upgrading my `RSpec-mocks gem` to `v3.6.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never liked `any_instance` so not sure how to do what you're wanting with it, however, an alternative that may do what you're wanting just as well is something like

```
class MyClass
  def track(a, b)
  end
end

def my_method(pass = true)
  MyClass.new.track('a', 'b')

  if pass
    2.times { MyClass.new.track('c', 'd') }
  end
end

RSpec.describe "SO question" do
  it 'pass' do
    first = double(MyClass)
    expect(first).to receive(:track).with('a', 'b')
    second = double(MyClass)
    expect(second).to receive(:track).with('c', 'd').twice

    allow(MyClass).to receive(:new).and_return(first, second)
    my_method
  end

  it 'fail' do
    first = double(MyClass)
    expect(first).to receive(:track).with('a', 'b')
    second = double(MyClass)
    expect(second).to receive(:track).with('c', 'd').twice

    allow(MyClass).to receive(:new).and_return(first, second)
    my_method(false)
  end
end
```

Bit more verbose, but forces the `new` method to return multiple instances that have expectations on them. [`and_return`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls) will return those values in order each time it's called and then will just keep returning the last value for any additional calls.

Comment: I tried with this 
`instances = Array.new(2) { double('Services::SegmentAnalytics') }` and was using instances[0] and instances[1]. I think I was a little confused with all the mixing n matching I was trying. Thanks, I got clarity from your answer.